# How can I do a comparison between boost::asio::buffer() and a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, sockets, buffer, netcat

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but my comparison does not work. I send a message x via netcat and compare it with a list of possibilities and see if the message is valid or not. But always the sentence "INVALID MESSAGE" is printed out, even if I send a valid message. Can someone help me?

```
void [blabla]::do_read()
{
    blabla
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf_, max_length),
    [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
    {
      std::string recv_msg = std::string(recv_buf_.begin(), recv_buf_.begin() + length);
      std::cout << "Received " << length << " bytes: " << recv_msg << std::endl;       
      command_check(recv_msg); // check if the command is valid or not
    });      
}


void [blabla]::command_check(std::string &comm)
{

  std::unordered_set<std::string> list_valid_commands {"all", "ackermann", "bitops",  "callfunc", "cdouble", "cfloat", "clongdouble"};

  SYSLOG_IF(ERROR, (list_valid_commands.find( comm) == list_valid_commands.end()) ) << "INVALID COMMAND";
}
```

Even if I type "all" for example, "INVALID COMMAND" is being printed out.

Comment: I'm not sure how `SYSLOG_IF` works, but `list_valid_commands.find(comm) != list_valid_commands.end()` is _true_ when `comm` is found in `list_valid_commands`.

Comment: have you tried printing `comm` or using a debugger? Please show a [mre]

Comment: I already tested it without using `SYSLOG_IF`. I think that the problem is comparing this: `std::string(recv_buf_.begin(), recv_buf_.begin() + length)` with this: `"all"`, for example. Idk if I can or cannot compare  a buffer with a string

Comment: You're comparing a `std::string` with a `std::string`. What gets printed out in `std::cout << ... << recv_message`?

Comment: In this line here `std::cout << "Received " << length << " bytes: " << recv_msg << std::endl;`, if I type "all" in the netcat, is being printed: `Received 4 bytes: all`

Comment: I also printed `comm` and the result in the console is also `all`.

Comment: `all` is only 3 characters so the fact you're recieving 4 suggests there's an extra invisible character in your string, maybe a null terminator?

Comment: I suspect the message is getting sent with a terminating null char. So the real fix is on the sending side. But if you can't fix that, just have your receive code chop off any leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: Small [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WTrMosqa9) of how constructing a string from a buffer that includes a null terminator can lead to oddities.

Comment: Thank you all, it worked using a trim function on the receiving side.